# Using For Looping

Tags: linux, linux-mint

here is what I need to do...

1. Name the script for.sh. This script will create a shopping list.
2. Ask the user to enter items separated by a space.
3. Use a for loop to write the items to a file called shopping_list. You should use >> to append the output to the file, so each time the script is run the list should get longer.
4. After the for loop finishes, display the contents of the shopping list.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I havent really tried anything yet, the video my instructor has for this online class is so hard to understand.  I did all the other problems because he made separate videos and he started from the start and I just followed along.  I have ZERO Linux experience and the way he teaches his class is if we are advanced users.  Its like all i know how to do is create the file and ask the user the questions, I get lost when I reached step 3, if I knew this is how the instructor was going to teach I would have chose a different elective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -

echo "Enter items separated by a space:"
IFS= read -r LIST

IFS=' ' # split on space only
set -o noglob # disable glob
for item in $LIST; do
   printf '%s\n' "$item" || break
done >> shopping_list
echo "List:"
cat shopping_list
```

Comment: do i add cat shopping_list to the whole command, or your saying that after the echo "List:" I should end it and than run the cat command?

Comment: That is up to you. If you desired to print the list file at the end, put it in you script.
Your item 4 says to display the contents of the file "after the for loop finishes", so keep the cat line at the end of script.

Comment: okay, thanks guys I really appreciate the help from you Eduardo Baitello and you as well Stephane Chazelas